# Local security settings

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, group-policy

is it possible to use `Get-GPOReport` command on a Client that is not in a Domain? I have a list of Group Policy Paths and trying to read them. Something like REG QUERY but with GPO`s "Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Password Policy\Enforce password history" Is one of the paths

What Im trying to achieve is, I have a hardened Win10 Client from that Client I want to query the Group policies. Later I want to query group policies of a non-hardened client and compare it with a hardened one to see which settings I need to change? I want to compare it with PolicyAnalyzer from Windows. I`ve tried LGPO and gpresult command but it doesn't show me all of the group policies.

Comment: No; One of the things the command requires doesn’t exist if the machine isn’t connected to a domain

Comment: Thank you and are there simmiliar commands to do it on a windows 10 client?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a non-Domain device, then of course there are no GPO's, as there are just LGPO's, as noted. So, looking to use that cmdlet is moot. Unless you are saying, the host was once part of a domain, then removed.

Anyway, see this Git repo to see if you can repurpose what the author is doing. [GPOReport](https://github.com/f-bader/GPOReport)

See also this:

```
Find-Module -Name '*policy*'

# Results
<#
Version              Name                                Repository           Description                                                                               
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------                                                                               
...
3.0.1                PolicyFileEditor                    PSGallery            Commands and DSC resource for modifying Administrative Templates settings in local GPO ...
...
#>


Import-Module -Name PolicyFileEditor
$UserTemplate = 'C:\Temp\Policy\Windows_10\user_registry.pol'
Get-PolicyFileEntry -Path $UserTemplate
```